# Updating the data in an ODBC datasource with that in local Access DB?

Tags: ms-access, vba, odbc, ms-access-2007

I have a remote ODBC data source 'A' whose values is to be updated according to the table 'B' in the local access database.  How can I do the same ?.  I tried using pass through queries, however I am not able to access both the remote and local source in ONE SINGLE query. How should I do the same?

How does link tables work? Can I link my local table to the ODBC database dynamically using VBA?

Answer (score 1):

In your Access database simply create a Linked Table for your ODBC data source:

[image: ODBC.png]

For detailed instructions, see

[About importing and linking data and database objects](http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/access-help/about-importing-and-linking-data-and-database-objects-HP005241695.aspx)

Once that is done, you can use the linked table and the local table(s) in the same query from within Access:

[image: Query.png]

Answer (score 0):

You can't create a link dynamically that I am aware, though you could refresh a link that already existed.

What sort of joining is required? If you're just updating a single or a few rows, you might do this: (I can only write this using ado (means adding a reference to microsoft.activex data objects)

```
dim ss as string 'tempstr, sqlstr whatever you want to call it

dim cn as object: set cn = createobject("adodb.connection")
cn.Connection = [connection string required for ODBC datasource]
cn.Open

dim rst as object: set rst = createobject("adodb.recordset")
rst.open "SELECT required_data_column_list FROM localTable [WHERE ...]" _
    , currentproject.connection, adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly
do while not rst.eof
    ss = "UPDATE ODBC_TableName SET ColumnA = '" & rst.Fields(3) & "' [, ... ]
    ss = ss & " WHERE ... "
    cn.Execute ss
    do while cn.State = adStateExecuting
    loop
    rst.movenext
loop
set rst = nothing     'these statements free up memory, 
set cn = nothing      'given that these objects are unmanaged
```

Hope this helps